API Requests fail about npm run build on my Flask App
I made an app using flask and react. There are frequent api calls I make to the backend. I used axios.
My issue is that my API calls are failing and I am unable to extract data from the backend to frontend. The only information I get is this insane long text:
"<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><title>React App</title><script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.9decc2a7.js"></script><link href="./static/css/main.a72eb3eb.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>"

When I tested it on localhost, it worked as intended.
For example, if I click a button to generate a string, it generates a string. However, after running 'npm run build' and 'serve -s build' on terminal, if I do the same thing on the localhost, it prints out this:
This is exactly what's on my index.html in my build directory. I have no idea why this is printing every time or why my API call to the backend is failing despite the code not changing. See images for reference

Here's the successful one before "build'
Here is the unsuccessful one

Can someone tell me what is going on?
I asked chatgpt, consulted several online resources, etc. However, I couldn't find any lead anywhere
If you are confused, I'll try to clarify
Thank you

It sounds like the server-side code is responding to these requests by returning the index page.  This wouldn't really have anything to do with React, but rather with the server-side code.  We'd need to know more about that, particularly about any given API endpoint and how it's being handled server-side.

It's a bit hard to tell what's going on since you're not showing any code or configuration, but I have an educated guess. You're presumably using your React dev tool's (e.g. React-Scripts (Create React App), Vite, etc.) proxy mode so your frontend can talk to the Flask app via e.g. /api/foo/ on the same port you're developing your frontend code on.
When you use npm run build, you get the frontend code that has been previously built, served (and e.g. hot-reloaded) by that dev tool as static HTML and JavaScript.
When you run serve, you get a server that only serves that static HTML; it doesn't know how to proxy things to the backend server.
If your goal is something that doesn't require the dev tool you're using, you would need to either

tell your backend server to serve the static assets, or
have a suitable web server (Nginx, Caddy, ...) to serve the static assets, and forward everything else to your backend application server.

